# How can I return all the name of the files in Resources folder in ios?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I want to retrieve in an array of the name of the files in Resources folder that have the `.html` extension. I have done this:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Resources"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *documentArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
for (int i=0; i < [documentArray count] - 1; i++) {
    NSLog(@"value %@", [documentArray objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

But the for loop displays continously null. Anyone knows how can I get this task right? thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `NSHomeDirectory`.  Use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]` to get path to app's resources.

Edited: here's your example code.

```
NSString *resPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *filenames = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:resPath error:&error];
if (!error)
{
    for (NSString * filename in filenames)
    {
        NSString *extension = [filename pathExtension];
        if ([extension isEqualToString:@"html"])
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok that...But now it returns all filesd. How do I specify html extension?